# Cordova BlinkID Emirates ID card scanning not returning name or number

Tags: android, cordova, blinkid

I want to scan emirates ID came across https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-cordova
created demo app following above github link

1. cloned above repo
2. executed `./initCordovaDemoApp.sh` to create demoApp
3. updated license keys in demoApp/www/js/index.js
4. built apk by `cordova build android`

it is scanning card on both sides, of scan success returning me 3 images only (front,back and face image)
but name, number, sex is empty.

after googling I found there might be issue with selected recognizer

in index.js it is as (default in above repo)

```
var blinkIdCombinedRecognizer = new cordova.plugins.BlinkID.BlinkIdCombinedRecognizer();
blinkIdCombinedRecognizer.returnFullDocumentImage = true;
blinkIdCombinedRecognizer.returnFaceImage = true;
```

I dont know how can I change recognizer and where can I find list of all recognizers for cordova and which one will be best to scan emirates ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, the SDK does not do OCR on Arabic script, so the only data the BlinkIdCombinedRecognizer extracts from UAE IDs are full name, nationality and document number.
You can retrieve those by accessing

```
blinkIdCombinedRecognizer.result.fullName
blinkIdCombinedRecognizer.result.nationality
blinkIdCombinedRecognizer.result.documentNumber
```

The recognizer also extracts data from the MRZ on the back and the applicable fields are available in

```
blinkIdCombinedRecognizer.result.mrzResult
```

You can check the [documentation](https://blinkid.github.io/blinkid-android/com/microblink/entities/recognizers/blinkid/mrtd/MrzResult.html) for a full list of MRZ fields, the mrzResult object will only return the ones contained in the MRZ of the actual document.